# How to read correctly the database of Firebase on the viewDidLoad() func?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
//Just a struct to save information about the User
var user = AppUser()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 //Verify if user is logged in
    verifyUser()
    user.email = "blabla"

    print("viewdidload user: \(user)")

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    print("viewdidappear user: \(user)")

} 

func verifyUser() {

    print("verify user called")

    //Log in verification
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
        perform(#selector(handleLogOut), with: nil, afterDelay: 0)

        print("nil user")

        return
    }

    ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.user = AppUser(dictionary: dictionary)

            print(self.user)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Console:

```
 verify user called


 viewdidload user: AppUser(id: nil, name: nil, email: 
 Optional("blabla"), completedRegister: nil, FULLUser: nil)


 viewdidappear user: AppUser(id: nil, name: nil, email:                
 Optional("blabla"), completedRegister: nil, FULLUser: nil)


 AppUser(id: nil, name: nil, email: Optional("x@gmail.com"),      
 completedRegister: Optional(false), FULLUser: Optional(false))
```

The question is simple. Can someone explain how is it possible that `"print("viewDidLoad user:....")"` is printed between "verify user called" and "the user" with the database information?

The problem is when I try to get information of the user on the viewDidLoad the function for some reason hasn't get the information so the values are still nil. Is it a question of time?

I tried to put a loop after the function verifyUser() but it never gets

```
out:

    while user.email == nil {
            print("Waiting...")
        }
```

So... thats the question

Thanks!

edit for Anas Menhar
This is my struct. Why would it be better to be a NSObject?
I did a Struct because I could do two different inits (one empty) and the NsObject didn't let me for some reason

```
struct AppUser {
var id: String?
var name: String?
var email: String?

var completedRegister: Bool?

var FULLUser: Bool?

init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
    self.email = dictionary["email"] as? String

    self.completedRegister = Bool((dictionary["completedRegister"] as? String)!)

    self.FULLUser = Bool((dictionary["FULLUser"] as? String)!)

}
init() {
    self.id = nil
    self.name = nil
    self.email = nil

    self.completedRegister = nil

    self.FULLUser = nil

}
}
```

edit for Hitesh

if I print the dictionary it prints just at the same time that the user completed with the information. At the end of everything.

Comment: Have you print `let dictionary = snapshot.value` ? can you add this?

Comment: show me your AppUser modal class which must be like                         class User: NSObject {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var imageURL: String?
}                                                                                                                  and also use this line                                 
user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `viewDidLoad()` calls `verifyUser()` before printing     `"viewdidload user: \(user)"`. Everything in `verifyUser()` will finish (with exception to your network call) before the print.

So here is the sequence of events happening for you:

1. `super.viewDidLoad()`
2. `verifyUser()` is called
3. print statement that is in `verifyUser()`
4. guard statement that is in `verifyUser()`
5. print statement in `viewDidLoad()`
6. `super.viewDidAppear()`
7. print in `super.viewDidAppear()`

Everything inside the closure for the .observeSingleEventOf will happen some point after 4 -- whenever that call finishes. If you want to do something when the call is finished, put it in the closure.

Like this:

```
 ref.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        self.user = AppUser(dictionary: dictionary)
        //***handle stuff that needs the user here
        print(self.user)
    } else {
        //***handle getting no data for the user or data that is not [String: AnyObject]
    }
}) { (error) in
    //***handle any errors here
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The places where I added comments are the places that would potentially be called when that request completes.

Side note: If you are going to use a Struct for AppUser, just make sure you know the differences between structs and classes. You could have a class named AppUser and have two different inits like this:

```
class AppUser {
    var id: String?
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
    var completedRegister: Bool?
    var FULLUser: Bool?

    ///initialization from a dictionary
    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        email = dictionary["email"] as? String

        if let completed = dictionary["completedRegister"] as? String {
            if completed == "true" {
                completedRegister = true
            } else if completed == "false" {
                completedRegister = false
            }
        }

        if let fullUser = dictionary["FULLUser"] as? String {
            if fullUser == "true" {
                FULLUser = true
            } else if fullUser == "false" {
                FULLUser = false
            }
        }
    }

    ///initialization without a dictionary
    init() {
        //dont need to set any variables because they are optional
    }
 }
```

---

```
let user1 = AppUser(dictionary: ["id": "12342",
                             "name": "John Doe",
                             "email": "email@email.com",
                             "completedRegister": "true",
                             "FULLUser": "true"])
    ///user1 properties:
    id: Optional("12342")
    - some: "12342"
    name: Optional("John Doe")
    - some: "John Doe"
    email: Optional("email@email.com")
    - some: "email@email.com"
    completedRegister: Optional(true)
    - some: true
    FULLUser: Optional(true)
    - some: true
```

---

```
let user2 = AppUser()
///user2 properties: none
```

Comment: which are the advantages of a class? Isnt the main difference that structs are value types and classes are reference types? So in my case a struct would do the work even better no? Last thing, why does the network stuff occurs after the rest of the viewDidLoad code? Thank you!!

Comment: Yes that's right. Classes being reference types make them a little bit more dynamic later as your functionality expands. The network calls begin in the order that you write them in, but they don't necessarily complete in that order. Imagine you're downloading a high-res photo that's 10mb and a low res photo that's 500kb. You can start them in any order, but (unless they're run synchronously) the 500kb will probably finish first.